# Are a pair of functions that have the same integral over all measures equal almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are $\lambda$-measurable and $$\int f\,d\mu=\int g\,d\mu$$ for all measures $\mu$ that are absolutely continuous with respect to measure $\lambda$. Does this imply that $f=g$ almost everywhere with respect to $\lambda$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give you a sequence of hints:

> Use $\mu = \chi_M \, d \lambda$, where $\chi_M$ is the characteristic function/indicator function of the set $M$.

$ $

> For a suitable choice of $M$ (like $M = \{x \mid f(x) \geq g(x)\}$), this should allow you to conclude $f -g \leq 0$ almost everywhere and $f - g \geq 0$ almost everywhere, at least if $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite.

$ $

> As you have no integrability assumptions on $f,g$ the $\sigma$-finiteness is important. You will also have to "truncate" $f,g$ using the set above, i.e. you should consider $M_n = M \cap \{x \mid |f(x)| \leq n \text{ and } |g(x)| \leq n\}$.

$ $

> You will then have to "truncate" even more using the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\lambda$, i.e. for $X = \bigcup_n X_n$ with each $X_n$ of finite measure, consider $M_n^k := M_n \cap X_k$.